# using geopandas to combine two geometries but retain the inner rings

Tags: union, overlay, geopandas

I have multiple geodataframes, I would like to combine them, however one contains an inner ring, I would like to retain the inner ring.

below is an image of what I'm trying to achieve green/blue are the two datasets.

Orange is the result I'm trying to achieve.

I've tried sjoin, overlay, dissolve, union, unary_union but I'm unable to get the orange result.

The attribute data does not matter.

[image]

My current workflow:

```
# merge all gdfs into one
gdf_combined = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    pd.concat([gdf1, gdf2, gdf3, gdf4]), ingnore_index=True))

# Next step:
sjoin, overlay, dissolve, union, unary_union
```

Comment: did you try to merge them before dissolve? meaning- to have the two geometries as one geodataframe and then dissolve

Comment: Yeah it would be helpful to see your code, including for the construction of your [mre]

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Geopandas preserving holes when union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75515175/geopandas-preserving-holes-when-union)

Comment: This looks very similar to your previous question. Rather than opening a new question, if you feel that question could be more clear, edit it to add information. Thanks!

Comment: It wont currently allow me to edit, but I currently `merge all gdfs into one` as shown, then I do `gdf_combined.dissolve()` this fills in inner rings, so not the solution I'm after.